# how to export tf model for serving directly from session (no creating of tf checkpoint) to minimize export time

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, export, tensorflow-serving

I wanted to share my findings on how to export a tf model for serving directly from session without creating model checkpoint. my use case requires minimum time to create a pb file, therefore I wanted to get a model.pb file directly from session without creating model checkpoint.

most examples online (and documentation refers to the common case of creating a model checkpoint and loading it in order to create a tf-serving (pb) file. of course this use case is good in case export performance time is not an issue.

Comment: be happy to get a comment on how to improve performance time of code below used to export the model (retaining all functionality used to get a servable pb file)

Comment: code below reduces export time (session ==> model.pb) by 50-80% depending on number of variables in the model, compared to original flow of session ==> model.ckpt ==> model.pb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import importer
output_path = '/export_directory' # be sure to create it before export
input_ops = ['name/s_of_model_input/s']
output_ops = ['name/s_of_model_output/s']
session = tf.compat.v1.Session()

def get_ops_dict(ops, graph, name='op_'):
    out_dict = dict()
    for i, op in enumerate(ops):
        out_dict[name + str(i)] = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.build_tensor_info(graph.get_tensor_by_name(op + ':0'))
    return out_dict


def add_meta_graph(pbtxt_tmp_path, graph_def):
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        importer.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
        os.unlink(pbtxt_tmp_path)

        # used to rename model input/outputs
        inputs_dict = get_ops_dict(input_ops, graph, name='input_')
        outputs_dict = get_ops_dict(output_ops, graph, name='output_')

        prediction_signature = (
            tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs=inputs_dict,
            outputs=outputs_dict,
            method_name=tf.saved_model.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

        legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
        builder = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(output_path+'/export')
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            session,
            tags=[tf.saved_model.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: prediction_signature},
            legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
        builder.save()
    return prediction_signature

def export_model(session, output_path, output_ops):
    graph_def = session.graph_def
    tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=graph_def, logdir=output_path, 
    name='model.pbtxt', as_text=False)

    frozen_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        session, graph_def, output_ops)

    prediction_signature = add_meta_graph(output_path+'/model.pbtxt', frozen_graph_def)
```

Comment: after creating a session, define some architecture, train... 
then use function export_model to get .pb file for tf-serving
get_ops_dict is used to rename model input/outputs
The graph is written as a text proto unless `as_text` is `False`. 
this has a significant impact on performance time !